# Why are the rows in a table of random digits labelled?

Tags: random, statistics, numbers, scipy.stats, schoology

[image]

We were looking at this in class and the - so far - unanswered question came up; why are the rows in this table labelled?

We still have no idea why this is.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question as stated.  This site is about coding related problems and your question doesn't seem to include any, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  also this seems to be about a proprietary system called schoology, maybe you have a support contract with them?

Comment: Adele, some methods of generating random numbers by hand involve jumping into a table of random numbers and then selecting whatever you find there. E.g. generate an index based on the number of minutes past the hour, then go to that index in the table and take the first 10 numbers you find. Obviously that's something people did before they had computers to generate numbers.